# Group membership requires confirmation from a group admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a group model and a user model. This is an m to n relationship. The group and user models are joined through a separate membership model.

Some subset of the users that belong to a group are administrators. When a new user tries to join a group by creating a new membership, I would like this action to be confirmed by one of the group administrators before the new user can actually participate in the group.

What is the best way of accomplishing this?  My current idea is to have a separate model called permission or invitation that only the group admins can create. A user is only a member of the group when they are part of both a membership and an invitation.  This seems like a lot of models for a fairly commonplace task. If this is actually the best approach, some advice on how to go about doing it would be greatly appreciated.

I don't want to use email for confirmation.

I am using Rails 3.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not include the confirmation status in the join model itself? So let's assume you have a User, a Group model and they are joined by a Membership model. Add an attribute "accepted_on" with format DateTime to the Membership model (or just a boolean if you don't care when exactly they were accepted.) Then make a view that lists all the memberships that's only visible to the admins with a link that only they can access which sets the "accepted_on" attribute to `Time.current`.

In your User/Group model you can then do the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, :conditions => 'accepted_on IS NOT NULL'
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, :conditions => 'accepted_on IS NOT NULL'
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

This way when a new user adds a membership it won't become available until the admin has accepted him (that is, made accepted_on anything other than nil.)